Ansible: Update Existing Variable List
I can define a variable/list in my main playbook (main.yml) or in my group variables (group_vars/all.yml) but the main.yml variables have precedence over the group variables.
group_vars/all.yml
my_list:
 - "item 1"
 - "item 2"

main.yml
  vars:
    my_list:
      - "item 3"
      - "item 4"

I would like to combine the two but am not sure how to do it. Desired:
my_list: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

I have tried adding to the list. For example if main.yml could see group_vars before overwriting (but this example throws an error).
    my_list:
     - "{{ my_list }}"
     - "item 3"
     - "item 4"

I am doing this because I am using code from another repository. I don't want to make changes to their code, but I do want to update (not overwrite) their variable list.

You can't do exactly what you want: you can only have one variable with a given name; there's no way to merge my_list in one place with my_list in another place. You can replace my_list, by doing something like:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_new_list_content:
      - item 3
      - item 4
    my_new_list: "{{ my_list + my_new_list_content }}"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_new_list }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_list

Assuming that group_vars/all.yaml contains:
my_list:
  - item 1
  - item 2

Then running the above playbook will produce as output:
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_list": [
        "item 1",
        "item 2",
        "item 3",
        "item 4"
    ]
}


Thank you. A little clunky but gets the job done!

Look at the plugins:

varnames
vars

These lookup plugins can help you to get what you want. For example, create variables with the common prefix my_list_ in the group_vars
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
my_list_gvars_all:
 - item 1
 - item 2

and in the playbook
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_list_pvars:
      - item 3
      - item 4

    my_list: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', 'my_list_.*')) |
                 flatten | unique | sort }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_list
      run_once: true

The lookup varnames gets the list of the variables matching the pattern and vars gets the values of the variables
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  my_list:
  - item 1
  - item 2
  - item 3
  - item 4

  ...

This framework is very flexible. For example, given the inventory
shell> cat hosts
test_01
test_02
test_03

Create host_vars
shell> cat host_vars/test_01.yml 
my_list_hvars_test_01:
  - item h01

shell> cat host_vars/test_02.yml 
my_list_hvars_test_02:
  - item h02

shell> cat host_vars/test_03.yml 
my_list_hvars_test_03:
  - item h03

Then, the below task (on all hosts)
    - debug:
        var: my_list | to_yaml
      # run_once: true

gives (abridged)
ok: [test_01] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h01]
ok: [test_03] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h03]
ok: [test_02] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h02]

You can add a temporary list with the scope of a single task
    - debug:
        var: my_list | to_yaml
      vars:
        my_list_tmp:
          - item tmp1
          - item tmp2

gives (abridged)
ok: [test_01] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h01, item tmp1, item tmp2]
ok: [test_02] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h02, item tmp1, item tmp2]
ok: [test_03] => 
  my_list: [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item h03, item tmp1, item tmp2]



Example of a complete playbook for testing
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_list_pvars:
      - item 3
      - item 4

    my_list: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', 'my_list_.*')) |
                 flatten | unique | sort }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_list | to_yaml
      # run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: my_list | to_yaml
      vars:
        my_list_tmp:
          - item tmp1
          - item tmp2

    - debug:
        var: my_list | to_yaml


